# Objective C Cocoa printing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to print a piece of text on a receipt with the Cocoa/Objective-C code, without any prompts. How to do this? Any example code or tutorial?

This documentation is to high level for me
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083-SW1

Comment: What do you mean "without any prompts"? Without displaying the printer dialog?

Comment: Yes without dialogs, I would like to make a cordova-plugin where javascripts calls a native objective-C method on OSX to print a receipt on a receipt printer.

Comment: How are you laying out/displaying the receipt? If you lay things out in a view, it can [natively print](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printapps/osxp_printapps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000861-BAJBFGED) directly; if you're looking to suppress the printing panel, you [can do that as well](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printpanel/osxp_printpanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000862-BAJBFGED).

Comment: I don't have a view in cordova I can only pass a string to the objective C code...

Comment: Is there any good documentation next to (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_pagination/osxp_pagination.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001051-BBCHHAHI), with example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the print panel by calling: In view you feed in the view in which the text to print is located.

```
  NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:aView printInfo:printInfo];
  [op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
  [op runOperation];
```

If you want to hide the progress panel, you can call `setShowsProgressPanel:NO` as well.

EDIT * Thats a different question anyway, here the solution: Provide a string. Create a new Textfield, feed the string in the textfield, and print out that textfield without dialog. Done!

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A String. \nA new string"];
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
[textField setStringValue:aString];
[textField setBordered:NO];
[textField sizeToFit];
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];

NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textField printInfo:printInfo];
[op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
[op runOperation];
```

Comment: Is there a way to just print a string? And not an NSView or NSDocument?

Comment: No! the method pointed it clear out. #printOperationWithView# feed in the view you want to print.

Comment: Is it possible to create a view from hard code and insert a string into it? Or is is absolutely necessary to drag a view element on a form and use that?

Comment: Thats an other question. Anyway I provided you a solution. It works!

Comment: Is there some documentation available on positioning the text on a receipt (80mm width paper)

Comment: Yes, the link you posted above. But it takes effort.

Comment: Are there any examples of a star TSP implementation?